# Django - Getting specific data from model

Tags: django, loops, logic

I'm trying to make a booking system (for apartments). The idea is that users can pick a start date and an end date and book the apartment if it isnt alrdy booked.

I have a Reservation model with a "start_date" and a "end_date" that I use to determine the dates for the apartment booking.

Users the JQuery Ui Date Picker (a small calendar)  to pick dates. The "unavailable" dates are grayed out. 
This is how I did that :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var unavailableDates = ['{{ reservation.all.0.start_date|date:"d-m-Y" }}', '{{ reservation.all.0.end_date|date:"d-m-Y" }}'];
        console.log(unavailableDates);
        function unavailable(date) {
            dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
            if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
                return [true, ""];
            } else {
                return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
            }
        }

        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'MM-dd-yy',
                beforeShowDay: unavailable
            });

        });
    </script>
```

I am using ...

```
{{ reservation.all.0.start_date|date:"d-m-Y" }}
```

...to gray out the date in the calendar.

My reservation model looks like this:

```py
class Reservation(models.Model):
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, related_name='reservations',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And in my view I have:

```py
def apartment_view(request, apartment_id):

    reservation = Reservation.objects.filter(apartment__pk=apartment_id)
    apartment = get_object_or_404(Apartment, pk=apartment_id)
    context = {'apartment': apartment, }

    form = ReservationForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ReservationForm()

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            reservation = form.save(commit=False)
            reservation.apartment = apartment
            reservation.save()
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/booking/')
    args = {}
    args['form'] = form
    args['apartment'] = context
    args['reservation'] = reservation
    return render(request, 'booking/apartment.html', args)
```

Since I need my reservations to be filtered to the correct apartment.

My question is, how can I query for ALL dates related to an apartment, both start and end dates ?

So I need all dates for apartment 1, then all dates for apartment2...etc.

I'm not sure how to go on about this, I apologize if the post is confusing.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Please add your entire view code. Im not entirely sure what you want to accomplish? You're talking about articles?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for answering. The article was a "typo". What I'm trying to acomplish is to get all reservations for a single apartment. So if i go to /apartment1/ there I have the reservations specific to apartment1, when I go to /apartment2/ I have the reservations specific to apartment2 etc..  I can access them 1 by 1 with doing {{ reservation.all.0.start_date|date:"d-m-Y" }}, but I need a way to get them all, and possibly save them to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later edit:
After looking at your JS code you might wanna do something like this in your view:

```
import itertools
unavailable_dates = apartment.reservations.values_list('start_date', 'end_date')
context['unavailable_dates'] = list(itertools.chain(*unavailable_dates)) # to convert _list_ of tuples to simple list
```

You can get start/end dates for reservations linked to an apartment like this:

```
apartment = get_object_or_404(Apartment, pk=apartment_id)
context['appartment_reservations_dates'] = apartment.reservations.values_list('start_date', 'end_date')
```

If you want to work with the entire `Reservation` object directly in your HTML template you can do it like this:

```
{% for reservation in apartment.reservation.all %}
    {{ reservation.start_date }} - {{ reservation.end_date }}
{% endfor %}
```

Your view might look like this:

```
def apartment_view(request, apartment_id):
    context = dict()

    context['apartment'] = get_object_or_404(Apartment, pk=apartment_id)
    context['reservations'] = apartment.reservations.all() # if you want all existing reservations for this specific appartment

    form = ReservationForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ReservationForm()

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): # you can add extra validation here making sure whoever tries to book is booking for an available time interval
            reservation = form.save(commit=False)
            reservation.apartment = apartment
            reservation.save()
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/booking/')

    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'booking/apartment.html', args)
```